# select tag with icon and text

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im running a code where I must create a drop down list with text and icon for each choice.
I used this code but got no answer.

```
<select>
<option style="background-image:url(btc.png);">btc</option>
<option style="background-image:url(eth.png);">eth</option>
<option style="background-image:url(xrp.png);">xrp</option>
</select>
```

I need to make some thing like this

[image]
I'm really stuck and need your help

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="dropdown mt-5">  
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">  
                Dropdown button  
            </button>  
            <div class="dropdown-menu">  
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home </a>  
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="fa fa-address-book"></i> Contact </a>  
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="fa fa-bell"></i> Notifications </a>  
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Setting </a>  
            </div>  
        </div>
```

Change icons with yours

https://fontawesome.com/v4.7/cheatsheet/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There you go ,try it :[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/o2z6bkxL/)

```
<div class="hero">
    <div class="selector">
        <div id="selectField">
            <p id="selectText">Select Social media</p>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down" id="arrow"></i>
        </div>
        <ul id="list" class="hide">
            <li class="option">
                <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
                <p>youtube</p>
            </li>
            <li class="option">
                <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
                <p>facebook</p>
            </li>
            <li class="option">
                <i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i>
                <p>whatapp</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```